# How to deploy a process from Signavio into jBPM?

Tags: jboss, jbpm, signavio

I've installed jBPM 4.4 and it looks neat.  I've edited a little example process using Signavio, and I'd like to deploy it on the demo server (`ant demo.setup.jboss`) so that I can see how it works.  But I can't figure out how to do that.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious...

Is the `.jpdl.xml` file all you need for a very basic deployment?  Is there a tutorial going through *every step* of defining a process and deploying it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can specify the path where signavio stores the files in the web.xml directory by setting the `fileSystemRootDirectory` context-param. Then use the jbpm-console to deploy the process from the same directory